# Enabling WMI and corresponding firewall exception via a Group Policy Object

Tags: windows, firewall, monitoring, group-policy, wmi

I have tried enabling WMI on my local domain using a group policy object which sets the service as on at startup.  In addition i added an exception for it via the windows firewall policy option for remote admin (something along those lines).  Some of my computers complied where as others have not and i can not get any WMI enabled systems to connect to them (e.g. for monitoring).

Am i doing something wrong here? any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the policy is setup correctly, it's just not being applied to some computers.

Check `gpresult` on the on the computers that don't have the policy to see if your policy was applied or not. If it hasn't run a `gpupdate /force` and check it again. If it still hasn't been applied, check to make sure whatever OU they are in, has the GPO applied to it as well. You can check what OU the computer is in if you're having issues by using `dsquery computer -name [name of computer]`